# In Slack, is there a way to filter out search results from a specific channel?

Tags: slack

I know you can do in:#channel to only get results from a channel, but is there a way to filter out results from a channel? A lot of our channels are spammed with automated messages and it adds noise to the search results.

Answer (score 55):

The search feature allows you to exclude words from the result by putting a minus sign in front of a word.

Examples:

```
hot -potato
```

will only return messages containing `hot`, but not `potato`.

To exclude a channel from the results use `searchTerm -in:channelName`. Do not add a `#` in front of the channel name.

Comment: Yes I know that but apparently that rule doesn't apply to channels. E.g.
`foo -in:#channel`
does not work

Comment: works on my machine :-) yet I needed to include the # sign. May have changed recently.

Comment: Interestingly, for me it only works if I *don't* include the `#`... ‍♂️

Comment: For me both of below filters worked, just make sure you are using correct channel name

my_search_term -in:#sfdc-pusher-alerts -in:us_demo_notes

Comment: Omitting thread comments from results with `-is:thread` did not seem to work for me.

Answer (score 8):

I found that this is possible as a global setting (which is less than convenient, but may still be useful). According to [this Help Center page](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/202528808-Search-in-Slack#filter-search-results) (Under the "Exclude channels from search" section):

1. From your desktop, click your workspace name in the top left.
2. Choose Preferences from the menu.
3. Click Search. *(I had to click "Advanced" under which there was a "Search Options" section)*
4. Under Don't search these channels *("Exclude these channels from search results" for me)*, click the box to pick channels to
   exclude.

Comment: Looks like the article has changed since, and I can't find where the information has moved. Unfortunately, I didn't have the foresight to archive it either...

Comment: It seems to work only for public channels through

Comment: This still works. Now under `Preferences > Advanced > Exclude these channels from search results:` Updated documentation link: https://slack.com/intl/en-ca/help/articles/4402305240723-Set-your-search-preferences

Answer (score 7):

For me both of below filters worked, just make sure you are using correct channel name

my_search_term -in:#sfdc-pusher-alerts -in:us_demo_notes

Comment: This works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is mentioned in their online help:

[image]

To get there, click on `Learn more` in Slack search box's bottom right corner:
[image]